# How to use linear geometry primitives fit a binary image

Tags: image-processing, graphics, computational-geometry

I have several binary images and my task is to use some linear geometry primitives to fit this binary image. The linear geometry primitives are triangle, quadrangle，octagon etc.
Just like the first following image, which can be fitted by two quadrangle, I have tried some methods but it doesn't work robustly. What can I do in this case in the image processing?
[image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlO0T.png)
[distance map, my segment method's example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMdfR.png)

Comment: Please share your code that you tried.

Comment: The code is a little bit more and it may be a little out of order. My idea is to compute every pixel's Manhattan Distance due to the distance between the pixel and the boundary, and then compute the center pixel due to Manhattan distance, the center pixel will be one linear geometry primitive and it will segment the binary image due to the center pixel.

Comment: Sorry, your explanation is perfectly opaque.

Comment: What you need is the [distance transformation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_transform)

Comment: yes, i have used distance map, and i deal with the local max distance's pixel as the center pixel. In a binary image, it may have more than one local max distances and there will be more than one center pixels. I will combine some neighbor center pixels. Next, other pixels will be computed to belong with one center pixel, so the binary image pixels will be clustered to the center pixels, and it will be segmented.

Comment: i lost you. can you post an image to visualize your problem. my imagination isnt the best ;)

Comment: okay, I have upload a new image to interpret my idea in my question. The grey pixel is the center, the blue pixels belong to the left center pixels and the red pixels belong to the right center pixels. thank you for all the replies.